# Eclipse - How do you change the font color of package explorer?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, gtk2

I'm running Eclipse Mars.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 on gtk2 (because it was freezing on gtk3).
The package explorer and open files tab have white fonts.
Is there any way to change this to black/default?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the package explorer color alone. But you can try different themes which are available in eclipse.

1. Open eclipse preferences
2. General -> Appearance -> Theme